# Run SQL server update command after clicking on DIV

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the Metronic admin template with my asp.net website.

There is a burger icon at the top of the page to hide the side bar.

http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/dashboard_2.html

When this is clicked I think a javascript runs and adds or removes a class for the sidebar div to show or hide it.

I would like to save the position of the side bar back to a sql server, so that when users visit the site it remembers the position of the sidebar.

For example I would like to run a SQL update command when the burger menu is clicked, and run the update command somehow.

I can change the class of the side bar on the page load by reading from a database.

But I cant work out how to run a SQL update command to update the database when the burger menu is clicked.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: you need to use ajax to send a message to your server-side code and tell it to update the database

Comment: thanks I see what you mean, I have this working now